# Parsing sets of variables from a string in a bat file

Tags: string, loops, parsing, batch-file

I have a situation where I'm trying to keep a static list of related items in a string and parse them out as sets in a bat file.

```
SET RootPath=C:\Users\woodh\test\
SET FromPath=StuffFrom\
SET ToPath=StuffTo\
SET CTLNames='text1.txt,red_text1:text2.txt,white_text2:text3.txt,blue_text3:'
```

With `CTLNames` containing pairs of entries to be parsed and consumed in the job.

I did the following

```
:Step20
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------
rem loop thru all files in the control list processing each pair at a time
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------
    FOR /F "delims=:" %%f IN (%CTLNames%) DO (

        IF NOT "%%f" == "" (

            CALL:BreakEntry "%%f"
        )
    )

:Finish
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------
rem -- Finish
rem ----------------------------------------------------------------
      goto end

:BreakEntry
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------
rem loop thru all files in the control list processing each entry one at a time
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------
    Set EntryLine=%~1

    IF NOT "%EntryLine%" == "" (

        ECHO %EntryLine%

        FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a IN ("%EntryLine%") DO (

            ECHO %%a
            ECHO %%b

            CALL:MoveThisFile %%a, %%b
        )

    )

goto:eof
```

But It's only processing the first pair of names and not continuing through the rest of the list.

Comment: Is it mandatory that __:__ separates the pairs (and __,__ separates a pair elements) in `CTLNames`?

Comment: Batch isn't a structured language, therefore I won't bother to read this horrid batch code (might be beautiful in another language but not batch). But you probably need to turn on `ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` (see `setlocal /?`). Refer to your variables !var!. See `for /?` for details (and an explanation as to why).

Comment: @bgalea - IMO the `rem` statements should be _above_ the label, there are a lot of unnecessary blank lines, and the commands don't need to be in all caps, but it's otherwise perfectly reasonable batch.

Comment: You should remove the single-quotes `'` from your `SET CTLNames='...'` command line because the become part of the variable value so you needed to handle them, and they don't have any special meaning in batch anyway; better put double-quotes `"` around the entire expression like `SET "CTLNames=..."` to avoid trouble with some special characters, and theyvdo _not_ become part of the variable value...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing. You didn't explained what exactly is the purpose of your code nor the expected output, so we can only guess. So *I guess* that you have a series of pairs of values separated by colon, and that each pair of values is separated by comma. This way, the problem with your code is that `for /F` command does *not* iterate over several values when just *one string* is processed: the string is divided accordingly to "tokens and delims" options and the command is executed *just one time*. You need to use a different method to process all substring in the string.

This is the way I would do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal

SET "CTLNames=text1.txt,red_text1:text2.txt,white_text2:text3.txt,blue_text3:"

for %%f in ("%CTLNames::=" "%") do (
   for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (%%f) do (

      echo %%a
      echo %%b

      echo CALL :MoveThisFile %%a, %%b
   )
)
```

I suggest you to remove the `@echo off` line and execute the program, so you may review what exactly is executed.

Comment: I like it! Thanks!  I have several jobs that im rewriting that have a lot of steps that could be replaced by this making the code much more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it doesn't work as expected (it only prints the 1st pair), is because [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) works on lines; `CTLNames` only consists of a line so a single iteration is needed.

The confusing part is that it still printed the 1st pair...that is because it actually did the split (on the 1st **:**) but by default `for` only cares about the 1st *token* (before the *delim*) and drops the rest. You can convince yourself by changing the line to:

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=:" %%f IN (%CTLNames%) DO (
```

you'll see that the value of `%%f` (because we instructed it to take all the tokens into account) is the whole line.

The reason why I asked if the *COLON*(**:**) is mandatory as a separator between pairs, is because you can also [iterate over a non numeric list](http://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html) - no `/f` flag, but here you can't specify the delimiter so you must use a regular one: *SPACE*( ), *COMMA*(**,**), *SEMICOLON*(**;**), *TAB*, and maybe others (anyway *COLON* is not one of them) - so this loop:

```
for %%f in (text1.txt:red_text1 text2.txt:white_text2 text3.txt:blue_text3;) do (
    echo %%f
)
```

- note that I used 3 separators: *TAB*, *SPACE* and *SEMICOLON* in the `for` loop (not sure how visible it is) -

would yield:

> text1.txt:red_text1
>
> text2.txt:white_text2
>
> text3.txt:blue_text3

Or you could use regular separators everywhere, and give up at the pair concept altogether, but I don't know if this is what you want.

I wasn't able to solve the problem using *COLON* as a separator from a single `for` loop, but I was able to find a way. Here's your script (slightly modified):

```
@ECHO OFF

rem ECHO %CTLNames%

CALL :Step20 "%CTLNames%"
GOTO :eof

:Step20
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------
rem loop thru all files in the control list processing each pair at a time
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------
    IF "" == "%~1" GOTO :eof
    FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%f IN ("%~1") DO (
        rem echo f: %%f
        CALL :BreakEntry "%%f"
        CALL :Step20 "%%g%
    )
GOTO :eof

:BreakEntry
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------
rem loop thru all files in the control list processing each entry one at a time
rem -----------------------------------------------------------------
    Set EntryLine=%~1
    ECHO %EntryLine%
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a IN ("%EntryLine%") DO (
        ECHO %%a
        ECHO %%b
        rem CALL :MoveThisFile %%a, %%b
    )
GOTO :eof
```

The main thing is (besides other small changes) that `Step20` is a recursive function (label), and it uses the `for` loop to split the line, it processes the 1st token, then it calls itself on the remaining tokens (until there are no more left).

Note: the single quotes surrounding `CTLNames` should be removed.